# Disable Debit Card Payment Method option

Tags: civicontribute

It looks like I can not disable the Debit Card option in CiviCRM.

It is safe to disable this option in the database? Is there another option?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are reserved payment option to which civicrm does not provide an option to disable or delete them.

Would recommend to first disable it from a development site database since this might result in an unnecessary fatal error as civi expects it to be available in multiple places. If you don't see any error - you can just repeat it on live.